# Self signed cert NodeJS rejectUnauthorized

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openssl

I created a structure certificates to authenticate client-> server, allowing only certificates recognized by the CA using this step by step: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html

I checked the authority with openssl, and it returns to me OK the certificate server and client, with the same CA. But by setting the parameter rejectUnauthorized to true on the server, the client can not connect.

Is there any extra parameter should I set up to allow authentication by a certificate that I generated?

---- Edit

On the client side I get the following error: ""ECONNRESET" socket hang up"

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time digging into a similar issue, and I wrote up this to talk about how to dig into various OpenSSL issues with node.js: http://www.thedreaming.org/2016/09/27/nodejs-ssl/

The short answer, though, is if you need to pass the `ca` parameter when creating you client connection.  If you have the self-signed certificate stored in `cert.pem`, then the client code looks something like:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');    
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert.pem');

var options = {
    host: serverHost,
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    ca: [certificate]
};
https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.pipe(process.stdout);
}).end();
```